# WebWorker and/or Storage Worker persist data in a way the web page can't access it

Tags: javascript, security, service-worker, indexeddb, web-worker

I need to store a highly sensitive data on the client, and preserve it from possible XSS. The best way I thought about were HttpOnly+Secure cookies, but unfortunately the data is too big, a little bit over the 4096 bytes limit.

The next idea I had is to create a WebWorker and/or ServiceWorker, and retrieve the data from inside it, and only using this data when receiving a message from the main page without passing it back to the page directly. And I need to persist this data for quite a long time.

Now, both WebWorkers and ServiceWorkers have access to indexedDB, but the main page also have access to it, so a possible XSS still can retrieve the data by querying the indexedDB store.

Is there a way to store the data so it could be only accessible by the Web/Service Worker which stored the data?

Or maybe some different approach alltogether? Storing the data on the server-side is the least wanted option.

Comment: And where does that sensitive info comes from to begin with? If someone spent enough resources to find an entry point in your system for an XSS attack, they probably had the time to read your Worker's code and find how to get that sensitive info directly, bypassing your Worker.

Comment: The data is actually encrypted JWT tokens, decrypted only on server side. I want to make the application as stateless as possible, that's why I prefer not to use the server storage.

Answer (score -1):

Never store sensitive data in the client. Client side storage is wholly insecure. Try storing the data server side, one-way hashing it, and saving only the hash client side. You can trivally do this with something like a SHA1 or SHA256 key. When requests are sent to the server, you can lookup by key. So you do not actually store the sensitive data in the client, just an obscure key that it uniquely corresponds to, that is otherwise meaningless if obtained by anyone.

Comment: While your answer is the most obvious and logical one, it defies my need to make the application as stateless as possible, and here we are basically introducing a state.